# Powershell script to automate the windows update along with optional updates

Tags: windows, powershell, automatic-updates

I was using below powershell script to update windows
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Execute-Windows-Update-fc6acb16#content

It works fine for **Windows updates**. But it does not install/update the **Microsoft Updates**

I am looking for script which automates Both **important** and **optional updates** as shown below.

[image]

How can I alter this script? (Script can be found in above link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module can be configured to use Microsoft update.

- https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.5.2.2
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

Force Windows update, using Microsoft update, accept all, and reboot

```
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
# register ms update service
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID "7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d" -Confirm:$false
Install-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -MicrosoftUpdate -AutoReboot
```

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/1.5.2.2  link is broken

Comment: I did not have to add ServiceId. It was already added.